# What is the implementation of array.copyWithin in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to copy some JS to a different programming language but am not getting this `copyWithin` function to work on an existing program (find and replace) with this:

```
function copyWithin(array, index, from, to) {
  while (from < to) {
    array[index] = array[from]
    from++
    index++
  }
}
```

My complicated program which is using this is failing when I replace:

```
array.copyWithin(index, from, to)
```

with

```
copyWithin(array, index, from, to)
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to replace this function with my own version.

```js
function copyWithin(array, index, from, to) {
  while (from < to) {
    array[index] = array[from]
    from++
    index++
  }
  return array
}

var array = [ {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}, {d:4}, {e:5} ]
console.log(array.concat().copyWithin(1, 3, 5))
console.log(copyWithin(array.concat(), 1, 3, 5))
```

I double checked and I'm not passing in any negative numbers.

Comment: It does exactly what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin#description) says it does. There is also a reference to other language constructs if you find that helpful. And finally, a polly fill that shows how the implementation is coded in case the browser doesn't support.

Comment: If index is in the range [from, to), then you need different logic depending on which way the two subranges overlap.

Comment: Oh wow I missed that polyfill. Is it really that complicated?

Comment: Running your code example with those indexes produces the same result from both functions.

Comment: Your snippet produces the same results on my end, I think.

Comment: You never mentioned which language. Most of JavaScript came from Java and C constructs. There is likely a solution that predates JavaScript's.

Comment: I tried using the polyfill and still not working. Hmm...

Comment: @LancePollard The complication comes from the fact that it can accept one, two or three arguments. Your function can only accept three arguments which makes things simpler. Do note that there is a hidden assumption in your code - that arrays works like javascript arrays which means that arrays can grow when you write to an index out of range. So assuming you have an array of size 1, writing to array[2] will expand it to size 3. If your language don't behave like javascript you will need to do some `realloc()` or need to initialize the `to` array to the correct size which you have not done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the arguments are within range, your function works correctly for when `index<from`. However, in the opposite case you would need to iterate in the opposite order. There is no need to create a new array.

Note that the native `copyFrom` method performs several checks, and can deal with missing arguments, negative indexes, array-like objects, ...etc. But if your aim is to only use this function with exactly 4 arguments, and non-negative indexes, and on native arrays, then the function could be as simple as:

```js
function copyWithin(array, target, start, end) {
    let shift = target - start;
    if (shift < 0) {
        end = Math.min(end, array.length);
        for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
            array[i + shift] = array[i]; 
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = Math.min(end, array.length - shift) - 1; i >= start; i--) {
            array[i + shift] = array[i]; 
        }
    }
    return array; // the array mutated, but it is handy to also return it.
}

let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(copyWithin([...a], 1, 3, 5));
console.log(copyWithin([...a], 3, 1, 3));
```

Comment: What did you do differently from what I originally did? Did you just handle the reverse case and that's it? (From the example in the original question). Maybe that was what was broken, not handling the reverse case. Not sure why my creating a new one worked either.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I just detected & processed the reverse case. (And added a check to avoid that the array would *grow* because of the copy).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyWithin(array, index, from, to) {
  let start = from
  let startIndex = index
  let newarray = []
  while (start < to) {
    newarray[start] = array[start]
    start++
    startIndex++
  }
  start = from
  startIndex = index
  while (start < to) {
    array[startIndex] = newarray[start]
    start++
    startIndex++
  }
}
```

Only this works, where I copied the array. The polyfill example on MDN doesn't work.

Now, how can this be simplified...

Comment: I don't think that's correct. According to the docs, "If `target` is positioned after `start`, the copied sequence will be trimmed to fit `arr.length`". But you don't seem to trim.

Comment: I don't know if this is a perfect implementation, but it allows my code to compile again haha.

Comment: Example: `a = [1, 2]; copyWithin(a, 1, 0, 2)`. After the call: `a == [1, 1, 2]`. Is this intended, or will such a situation never occur in your scenarios?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't checked deeply enough, I am going off of the usage in the b+tree algorithms you made a little while back, where `copyWithin` was used. It seems to be working, but it looks like you found a bug that isn't popping up yet.